# VueJS Unit Test Error - Not implemented: window.open

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, window.open, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to write unit test using chai and mocha.But getting this error while running test. Can anyone please help me here.

Answer (score 2):

You can mock your window.open function like this.

```
it ('function with window.open', (done) => {
   window.open = function(url) {
     // you can define your own window.open function
     expect(url).toBe(originUrl);
     done();
   };
});
```

Good luck!